# Getting all selected checkboxes in an array to POST to API

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, checkbox, form-data

I want to Getting all selected checkboxes in an array to `POST` to API by `urlencoded.append`

```js
urlencoded.append("typeID", (document.getElementById("type").value==1?"1":document.getElementById("type").value==2?"2":"3"));
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="1" id="type-id">
  <label>Food Deals</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="2" id="type-id">
  <label>Groceries Deals</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="3" id="type-id">
  <label>Karam Box</label>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: your HTML is invalid, id must be unique...

Comment: @MisterJojo I edit it

Comment: that the same, your 3  checkbox have the same ID, so they are not unique.

Comment: @FadyNabil ... the checkbox `id` values are still not unique (3 times `id="type-id"`). Also there is no reason at all to provide an `id` attribute to each checkbox control.

Comment: @FadyNabil ... From all the provided solutions/approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: @FadyNabil ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***prepended EDIT***

[It looks like the OP already has access to a `FormData` instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761332/getting-all-selected-checkboxes-in-an-array-to-post-to-api/69761557#comment123318563_69761557) which in the OP's example code gets referred to as `urlencoded`.

Thus in order to provide a quick fix for the OP's code, a solution might look like this ...

```
// make an array from the ...
Array.from(
  // ... node list of every checked
  // ckeckbox control withing the #myDiv element ...
  document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv [type="checkbox"]:checked')
)
.reduce((formData, control) => {

  // ... and append key/name and value to `formData` ...
  formData.append(control.name, control.value);
  return formData;

  // ... which is represented by the `urlencoded` object
  // that got provided as the `reduce` task's initial value.
}, urlencoded);
```

Further below one finds a fully-fledged and working example code in order to study the use of [`XHR`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

***+++ edit end +++***

In addition to the logging check your `DevTools` `Network` tab as well. One should be able to inspect a failed (404) `POST` request to `https://stacksnippets.net/` but with the correctly sent form data.

The provided approach uses a form element where it intercepts and prevents the browser's form submit but creates an own XHR from the form's [`method`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/method) and [`action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/action) values.

In order to collect/aggregate the form data it uses the [`FormData` Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). Such an object can be directly passed to the XHR's [`send`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) method.

```js
function createXHRFromForm(form) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

  xhr.open(
    form.method,
    form.action,
    true
  );
  xhr.setRequestHeader(
    'Content-Type',
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  );
  // xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  //   if (
  //     (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
  //     && (this.status === 200)
  //   ) {
  //     // handle success
  //   }
  // };
  return xhr;
}
function createCheckboxFormData(form) {
  // for the given example form
  // following line already was sufficient enough
  //
  // return new FormData(form);
  //
  // but a custom aggregation is supposed to be shown.
  return Array
    .from(
      form.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked')
    )
    .reduce((formData, control) => {

      formData.append(control.name, control.value);
      return formData;

    }, new FormData); 
}

function handleCheckboxDataSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  
  const form = evt.currentTarget;

  const xhr = createXHRFromForm(form);
  const formData = createCheckboxFormData(form);

  console.clear();
  console.log({
    entries: [...formData.entries()],
    name: formData.getAll('name'),
  });
  xhr.send(formData);

  return false;
}

function main() {
  document
    .querySelector('form[name="myForm"]')
    .addEventListener('submit', handleCheckboxDataSubmit);
}
main();
```

```css
:not([type="submit"]) {
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
}
body { zoom: .85; }
label { display: block; cursor: pointer; }
[type="submit"] { margin-top: 3px; }
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="/" method="post">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="1" checked/>
    <span class="label">Food Deals</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="2" checked/>
    <span class="label">Groceries Deals</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="3"/>
    <span class="label">Karam Box</span>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">POST</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of notes:

1. In `HTML` (and the reality) id's are unique.
2. In `JS` the selected checkbox are `checked` and not `selected`.

In order to collect all checked values you can do something like that:

```js
function demo() {
  document.querySelectorAll('input:checked').forEach(element => {
    console.log(element.value);
  });  
}
```

```html
<div>  
  <label>1<input type="checkbox" value="1" /></label>
  <label>2<input type="checkbox" value="2" /></label>  
  <label>3<input type="checkbox" value="3" / ></label>
  <label>4<input type="checkbox" value="4" /></label>
  <label>5<input type="checkbox" value="5" /></label>  
  <label>6<input type="checkbox" value="6" / ></label>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="demo()">"POST"</button>
```

Comment: @a-meshu this work good with me to view values on console log
but not work with me to post to API
        
urlencoded.append("typeID", document.querySelectorAll('input:checked').forEach(element => {console.log(element.value)}));

Comment: @FadyNabil ... we don't even know what `urlencoded` or `urlencoded.append` is supposed to be/mean. And you neither because if `append` is a method which expects arguments then one can not execute `document.querySelectorAll('input:checked').forEach(element => {console.log(element.value)})` as its 2nd argument and expect something meaningful to happen. Have a look into the approach I did provide. There you find a fully-fledged and working example code in order to study the use of `XHR` and `FormData`. My guess is that your `urlencoded` object actually is a `FormData` instance.

Comment: @FadyNabil what exactly are you trying to do? My basic snippet demonstrate how you can get all values from checked inputs. Instead `console.log` them - you can do with it whatever you want (: